# Conditional columns in DECLARE @Local TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't seem to find a proper solution to declaring conditional columns in a local table.

The 2nd table have an extra column `SnapshotURL`.

```
DECLARE @product_major_version int;
SELECT @product_major_version = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS int);

IF (@product_major_version <= 12)
    DECLARE @FileList TABLE 
    ( 
        LogicalName            NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL 
        , PhysicalName         NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL 
        , Type                 CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
        , FileGroupName        NVARCHAR(120) NULL 
        , Size                 NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , MaxSize              NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , FileId               BIGINT NULL 
        , CreateLSN            NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DropLSN              NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , UniqueID             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , ReadOnlyLSN          NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , ReadWriteLSN         NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , BackupSizeInBytes    BIGINT NULL 
        , SourceBlockSize      INT NULL 
        , FileGroupId          INT NULL 
        , LogGroupGUID         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseLSN  NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , IsReadOnly           BIT NULL 
        , IsPresent            BIT NULL 
        , TDEThumbprint        VARBINARY(32) NULL  
    );
ELSE
    DECLARE @FileList TABLE 
    ( 
        LogicalName            NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL 
        , PhysicalName         NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL 
        , Type                 CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
        , FileGroupName        NVARCHAR(120) NULL 
        , Size                 NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , MaxSize              NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , FileId               BIGINT NULL 
        , CreateLSN            NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DropLSN              NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , UniqueID             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , ReadOnlyLSN          NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , ReadWriteLSN         NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , BackupSizeInBytes    BIGINT NULL 
        , SourceBlockSize      INT NULL 
        , FileGroupId          INT NULL 
        , LogGroupGUID         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseLSN  NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , IsReadOnly           BIT NULL 
        , IsPresent            BIT NULL 
        , TDEThumbprint        VARBINARY(32) NULL
        , SnapshotURL          NVARCHAR(360) 
    );
```

The problem with this approach is that `@FileList` is declare twice.

I can't use `ALTER TABLE` as it's not supported.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Remove the `if` condition and add the `SnapshotURL` column all the time. That would be much better than what you are looking for

Comment: This lead me on the right path. Obviously all I needed to do was make `SnapshotURL` nullable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good suggestion from Pரதீப்

Or you can try with `TempTable` instead?

```
 DECLARE @product_major_version int;
SELECT @product_major_version = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS int);

CREATE TABLE #FileList
    ( 
        LogicalName            NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL 
        , PhysicalName         NVARCHAR(260) NOT NULL 
        , Type                 CHAR(1) NOT NULL 
        , FileGroupName        NVARCHAR(120) NULL 
        , Size                 NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , MaxSize              NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL 
        , FileId               BIGINT NULL 
        , CreateLSN            NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DropLSN              NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , UniqueID             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , ReadOnlyLSN          NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , ReadWriteLSN         NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , BackupSizeInBytes    BIGINT NULL 
        , SourceBlockSize      INT NULL 
        , FileGroupId          INT NULL 
        , LogGroupGUID         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseLSN  NUMERIC(25, 0) NULL 
        , DifferentialBaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL 
        , IsReadOnly           BIT NULL 
        , IsPresent            BIT NULL 
        , TDEThumbprint        VARBINARY(32) NULL  
    );

IF (@product_major_version <= 12)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE #FileList
    Add     SnapshotURL     NVARCHAR(360) 
END
```